# Delete records by limit and condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I have a table named `log` in one of MySQL database. And it is used to log the user actions. When it becomes very large in size, I want to delete some records.

```
SELECT `userid`, `timestamp` 
FROM `log`
ORDER `timestamp` ASC
```

the output is

```
userid    timestamp
     2    120000
     3    123333
     1    123456
     1    124444
     2    125555
     2    126666
     1    127777
     1    128888
     2    129999
     3    130000
     1    131111
```

What I want to do is that - I want to ***keep only last 3 records*** for each user. 
So, I need to delete the 4th, 5th, ..., nth records for each user.
According to the above sample, the desire output is

```
userid    timestamp
     3    123333
     2    125555
     2    126666
     1    127777
     1    128888
     2    129999
     3    130000
     1    131111
```

I know that records can be deleted by using `LIMIT`.

```
 DELETE FROM `log` LIMIT 3
```

deletes only 3 records. It simply cannot get my desire result.

What I have tried is that

```
DELETE FROM
`log`
WHERE `userid` IN (
SELECT `userid` FROM (SELECT `userid`, COUNT(1) AS C
FROM `log`
GROUP BY `userid`
HAVING C > 3) CountTable ) LIMIT 3
```

And it is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE l FROM `log` l 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT l.userid, l.timestamp
           FROM (SELECT l.userid, l.timestamp, 
                        IF(@lastUserId = @lastUserId:=userid, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=0) rowNumber 
                 FROM `log` l, (SELECT @lastUserId:=0, @Idx:=0) A
                 ORDER BY l.userid, l.timestamp DESC
                ) AS A
           WHERE rowNumber < 3
          ) AS A ON l.userid = A.userid AND l.timestamp = A.timestamp 
WHERE A.userid IS NULL
```

**EDIT:**

```
DELETE l FROM `log` l 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM (SELECT l.userid, l.timestamp, 
                       IF(@lastUserId = @lastUserId:=userid, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=0) rowNumber 
                FROM `log` l, (SELECT @lastUserId:=0, @Idx:=0) A
                ORDER BY l.userid, l.timestamp DESC
               ) AS A
          WHERE l.userid = A.userid AND l.timestamp = A.timestamp AND rowNumber < 3
         )
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3444/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| USERID | TIMESTAMP |
|--------|-----------|
|      3 |    123333 |
|      2 |    125555 |
|      2 |    126666 |
|      1 |    127777 |
|      1 |    128888 |
|      2 |    129999 |
|      3 |    130000 |
|      1 |    131111 |
```

Comment: I get Error `#1064`. I get more idea from answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: still get Error #1064, but when I try ... `SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT l.userid, l.timestamp , IF( @lastUserId = @lastUserId := userid, @Idx := @Idx +1, @Idx :=0 ) rowNumber
FROM  log l, (
SELECT @lastUserId :=0, @Idx :=0
)A
ORDER BY l.userid, l.timestamp DESC
) A
` is ok. It shows `rowNumber` correctly.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Can you explain the problem with fiddle demo so I can find what is the problem

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12d65b/2/0) is ok - when I try `DELETE`, it says _DDL and DML statements are not allowed_

Comment: sorry I have to try `DELETE` in schema panel

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Check my updated answer. I had rewrite my query from `DELETE FROM` to `DELETE l FROM`.

Comment: Great! It also works in my machine! +1 and accepted answer! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL:

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE find_in_set(
    TIMESTAMP, (
        SELECT group_concat(t3) t4 FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS dummy,
            replace(group_concat(TIMESTAMP ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC), concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(TIMESTAMP ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC), ',', 3), ','), '') t3
            FROM log
            GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) > 3
        ) a GROUP BY dummy
    )
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06541/3)